# USing Group BY in MYSQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am querying data from  two related tables, I would like to use Count function with group by clause but no data is showing,

Here is my query

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Categoryname, c.Longdesc, 
CASE WHEN c.productType = 0 THEN "Services" ELSE "Products" END As ProductType,
COUNT(c.Categoryname) AS Total
 FROM category As c
 INNER JOIN products p
 ON c.Id = p.categoryId
 WHERE c.Active = true AND c.ShowtoAll = false
 GROUP BY c.Categoryname;
```

What might be wrong with my query?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In order to effectively help you, we need to reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: It's likely a memory problem. Have you large objects in your session? Try reporting `sum(sapply(ls(), function(name) object.size(get(name)))) / 1024^3`.